# Why does linq-2-sql create extra unnecessary objects?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, orm

I have a simple Parent Child table in a database like so

```
CREATE TABLE [Parent](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL)    
ALTER TABLE [Parent] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Parent_Id] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])    

CREATE TABLE [Child](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL)    
ALTER TABLE [Child] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Child_Id] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
ALTER TABLE [Child] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Child_Parent_ID] 
    FOREIGN KEY([ParentId]) REFERENCES [Parent] ([Id])
```

The data that I have in them is

**Parent Table**

```
Id  Name
1   John
```

**Child Table**

```
Id ParentId  Name
1     1    Mike
2     1    Jake
3     1    Sue
4     1    Liz
```

These tables are mapped to `Parent` and `Child` C# objects using the Linq-2-SQL designer in Visual Studio with no non standard options.

I made a simple test program to query all child with their parents

```
public partial class Parent
{
    static int counter = 0;
    //default OnCreated created by the linq to sql designer
    partial void OnCreated()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("CreatedParent {0} hashcode={1}",
            ++counter , GetHashCode()));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new SimpleDbDataContext())
        {
            DataLoadOptions opts = new DataLoadOptions();
            opts.LoadWith<Child>(c => c.Parent);
            db.LoadOptions = opts;
            var allChildren = db.Childs.ToArray();
            foreach (var child in allChildren)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Parent name={0} hashcode={1}",
                    child.Parent.Name, child.Parent.GetHashCode()));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the above program is

```
CreatedParent 1 hashcode=53937671
CreatedParent 2 hashcode=9874138
CreatedParent 3 hashcode=2186493
CreatedParent 4 hashcode=22537358
Parent name=John hashcode=53937671
Parent name=John hashcode=53937671
Parent name=John hashcode=53937671
Parent name=John hashcode=53937671
```

As you can see a `Parent` object was created for every `Child` in the database only to be discarded eventually.

Questions:

1. Why does Linq-2-Sql create these unnecessary extra `Parent` objects ?
2. Are there any options to avoid creation of extra `Parent` objects ?

Comment: It doesn't create singleton objects as you are expecting and nor should it. What would happen if you had one query that selected one object and you start writing an update query on the same id? Should you immediately see the results of the change before submitting the changes? A unique instance is created for each query.

Comment: @JeffMercado, no: L2S only hands out one instance per table and key. This is an important feature of ORMs (identity map).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a side-effect of the way, `LoadWith` is implemented. LINQ to SQL converts your query internally to:

```
from c in children
select { Child = c, Parent = c.Parent }
```

As you can see, we are loading the Parent once for every child (an inner join). This effect is not normally visible because of the identity map. ORMs make sure that entity objects are never duplicate by (table, primary key). This comes in handy when you do updates.

LINQ to SQL reads the result set returned from the server (it contains the same Parent N times!) and materializes it into objects. Only after materialization is done, the identity map does its job and discards the duplicate parent instances.

**The same effect works for all queries returning the same entity multiple times.**

Comment: Exactly it is an inner join. It is like writing this query and running in SSMS. SELECT * FROM child JOIN parent on child.ParentId = Parent.Id... when you run this query you get parent id for each child nothing new, in fact here VS is following the standard footsteps of SQL standard.