# Why does Linq-to-SQL add unnecessary COUNT()?

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Here are my tables:

```
create table customer 
(
    cid int primary key,
    name varchar(32)
)

create table ord 
(
    oid int primary key,
    cid int foreign key references customer,
    address varchar(20)
)
```

Here's my Linq-to-SQL statement:

```
var aaa = from c in db.Customer
          select new { c, o = c.Ord.ToList() };
```

And here's the inexplicable query generated by Linq-to-SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [t0].[cid] AS [Cid], [t0].[name] AS [Name], [t1].[oid] AS [Oid], 
    [t1].[cid] AS [Cid2], [t1].[address] AS [Address], 
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM [dbo].[ord] AS [t2]
     WHERE [t2].[cid] = [t0].[cid]) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[customer] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ord] AS [t1] ON [t1].[cid] = [t0].[cid]
ORDER BY [t0].[cid], [t1].[oid]
```

I want to understand how to get rid of that `COUNT(*)` part. It's entirely uncalled for!

Comment: Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997048/why-does-linq-2-sql-create-extra-unnecessary-objects/12045296#12045296

Answer (score 1):

LINQ needs the `COUNT(*)` in order to determine the number of entries that will be returned for the `o = c.Ord.ToList()`.

Comment: Why is there such need? Couldn't they just keep expanding the list things as they come? The problem I have is that this query generates a query plan that's N^2 where N is the number of orders per customer (which is large in my case). I'm quite frustrated with it. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Consider how the SQL returns the data - you have `t0` (customer) fields repeated matched to each `t1` (ord) field in a flat list of records. (SQL only returns tables.) Somehow LINQ must create a customer record merged with n ord records from this. Having the count available makes this much easier. I don't see how it can be done differently without querying the database per customer for the ord records. I assume you are using Entity Framework? What happens if you change to `(from c in db.Customer select c).Include("ord")` ?

Comment: It's the old-school linq2sql, not EF. I imagine it like this: LINQ is reading incoming records, and for each one it would create a new Customer object (if not created earlier) and then add the Order part of the result rowset to the corresponding Customer (looked up by customer id). There is no need to know how many Orders you're getting - just keep piling them on as they come in. Oh well.